# Why does my application using OmniThreadLibrary Parallel.Pipeline continue remain running in the background after being closed?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe7, omnithreadlibrary

I'm using OmniThreadLibrary to implement a background pipleline for sending emails (refer to this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30779068/1992767)). I notice that after closing the application, it continues running in the background (seen in Windows Task Manager). That means that there is something wrong in my code in the way I implemented the OTL pipeline. Can you help me identify the trouble?

Code follows:

```
unit uEmailQueue;

interface

uses Classes, OtlCommon, OtlCollections, OtlParallel, Windows;

type
  TEmailServer = record
    SMTPHost: String;
    SMTPPort: Integer;
    SMTPUseSSL: Boolean;
    SMTPUserName: String;
    SMTPPassword: String;
    SMTPSenderName: String;
  end;

  TEmailMessage = record
    RecipientEmailAddr: String;
    EmailSubject: String;
    EmailMessage: String;
  end;

  TEmailQueue = class(TObject)
  private
    FEmailServer: TEmailServer;
    FPipeline: IOmniPipeline;
    procedure SendEmailStage(const input, output: IOmniBlockingCollection);
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SendEmail(AEmailMessage: TEmailMessage);
  end;

implementation

{ TEmailQueue }

procedure TEmailQueue.SendEmailStage(const input, output: IOmniBlockingCollection);
var
  mailmessage: TOmniValue;
begin
  for mailmessage in input do
  begin
    Beep(3700, 1500); // just some dummy code for now
  end;
end;

constructor TEmailQueue.Create;
begin
  FPipeline := Parallel.pipeline.Stage(SendEmailStage).Run;

end;

destructor TEmailQueue.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TEmailQueue.SendEmail(AEmailMessage: TEmailMessage);
begin
  FPipeline.input.Add(TOmniValue.FromRecord(AEmailMessage));

  // FPipeline.input.CompleteAdding;

  // FPipeline.WaitFor(INFINITE);

end;

end.
```

I initialize and call the above class like this:

In the application's main form's OnCreate event:

```
  FEmailQueue := TEmailQueue.Create;
```

A button on the main form has this in the OnClick event:

```
var
  em: TEmailMessage;
begin
  FEmailQueue.SendEmail(em);
```

later, I free the class like this in the main form's OnDestroy event:

```
  FEmailQueue.Free;
```

Comment: `procedure TEmailQueue.SendEmail(AEmailMessage: TEmailMessage);` I bet that is not efficient, I think you better make A EmailMessage either into a const-parameter or into a var-parameter.

Comment: @Arioch'The Probably. If it was made const, then would it (also) prevent creating duplicate strings in memory (like var), and thus be faster?

Comment: No, strings (except TurboPascal's ShortString[nnn] type and except MS-COM WideString type) like interfaces and dyn-arrays are ref-counted types, so strings themselves should not be copied when copying `TEmailMessage`

Comment: OTOH, post-XE1 Delphi is broken w.r.t. strings, so I would not be overly surprised if const'ing the parameter would save a something more than merely copying pointers and calling few Atomic-Increments  http://kazav.blogspot.ru/2014/01/delphi-2.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `FPipeline.input.CompleteAdding` from `TEmailQueue.Destroy`. Otherwise, `SendEmailStage` will never stop.